# Screen management and loading functions in kivy PYTHON

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So, I'm doing this GUI that has the main screen and a loading screen. The loading screen is used so that the user can see the progress of the application while the program executes a function. I want the program to change to execute the function and switch back to the main screen once the functions are executed. Here is part of my code that you can use to run the program on your end.

```
# Imports
import kivy
from kivy.app import App    # Imports functions to build the app
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import threading
import time

kivy.require('1.10.1')


def function1():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done")


def function2():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done 2")


class MainScreen(Screen, FloatLayout):  # Main Screen Class that holds every method in the Start Screen

    auction_name = " "
    default = "Select an auction"
    selected_auction = StringProperty('Select an auction')
    x_value = 450
    y_value = 500

    def change_label(self, change):  # Changes the text that shows what auction is selected

        strtst = "Selected: " + change

        if self.selected_auction == self.default and (change == "Copart" or change == "IAAI"):
            self.selected_auction = "Selected: " + change
            self.selected_auction = "Selected: " + change
        elif self.selected_auction == strtst or self.selected_auction == "Main":
            self.selected_auction = self.default
        elif change != self.selected_auction:
            if self.selected_auction == "Selected: Copart and IAAI":
                self.selected_auction = "Selected: " + change
            else:
                if change == "None":
                    self.selected_auction == "TO START, PLEASE SELECT AN AUCTION"
                else:
                    self.selected_auction = "Selected: Copart and IAAI"

    def change_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = "Loading Screen"

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=function1)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=function2)

    def start_process(self):  # Used to start the web scraping
        if self.selected_auction == 'Selected: Copart':
            self.manager.current = "Loading Screen"
            self.t3.start()
            self.manager.current = "Results Screen"
            self.selected_auction = "Select an auction"
        elif self.selected_auction == 'Selected: IAAI':
            self.manager.current = "Loading Screen"
            self.t2.start()
            self.selected_auction = "Select an auction"
        elif self.selected_auction == 'Selected: Copart and IAAI':
            self.manager.current = "Loading Screen"
            self.t2.start()
            self.t3.start()
        else:
            self.change_label("None")


class LoadingScreen(Screen):

    def cancel(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        padding = Label(text= "If you say yes all progress will be lost!")
        buttons = BoxLayout()
        warning = Image(source="Data/warning.png")
        yes_button = Button(text= "Yes, do cancel it.", on_release=lambda x:self.back(),
                        on_press=lambda *args: pop.dismiss(), size=(250, 120), background_color=(300, 0.5, 0, .7))
        no_button = Button(text="No, don't cancel.", on_press=lambda *args: pop.dismiss(), size=(250, 120),
                       background_color=(.25, 150, .04, 0.5))
        box.add_widget(warning)
        box.add_widget(padding)
        buttons.add_widget(yes_button)
        buttons.add_widget(no_button)
        box.add_widget(buttons)

        pop = Popup(title="Do you wish to cancel?", content=box, size_hint=(None, None), size= (800, 500))
        pop.open()


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    main_screen = ObjectProperty(None)
    loading_screen = ObjectProperty(None)


class MainApp(App):

    choice = ""
    source = StringProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=NoTransition())
        return m


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Window.clearcolor = (.46875, .46875, .4765, 1)
    Window.size = (850, 1000)
    MainApp().run()
```

In the Main Screen, there is a button that when pressed should change the screen and executed the function, which is handled using `start_process()`. Here is my main.kv file:

```
#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#: import ProgressBar kivy.uix.progressbar
#: import Widget kivy.uix.widget
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#: import Popup kivy.uix.popup
#: import main gui_test

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    main_screen: mainS
    loading_screen: loadingS

    MainScreen:
        id: mainS
        name: "Main Screen"
        manager: screen_manager

    LoadingScreen:
        id: loadingS
        name: "Loading Screen"
        manager: screen_manager


<MainScreen>
    FloatLayout:

        # Start Button
    Button:
        on_release: root.start_process()
        text: "Start"
        font_size: 16
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.12
        pos: root.center_x - (self.width/2), root.y + self.height
        background_normal: ''
        background_down:
        background_color: .25, .75, .04, 1
        font_size: 50

    # COPART BUTTON
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.279, 0.3
        pos: root.x + (0.3 * self.width), root.top - self.height - 160
        on_press: root.change_label("Copart")

    # IAAI BUTTON
    Button:
        id: IAAI_Button
        size_hint: 0.27, 0.3
        pos: root.x + (1.7 * self.width) + 300, root.top - self.height - 160
        on_press: root.change_label("IAAI")

    Label:
        text: root.selected_auction
        font_size: 50

<LoadingScreen>
    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "Cancel"
            size_hint:0.30, 0.1
            pos: root.center_x - (self.width/2), 100
            background_color: 300, 0.5, 0, .4
            on_press: root.cancel()
```

Do you have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You probably need to run your function in another thread. Otherwise, your function is hogging the main thread and not allowing the `LoadingScreen` to update.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I've been trying to implement threading into my program. I use a method inside the MainScreen class to change the screen to the loading screen. This method takes `self` as its only parameter. So when I run the program I get the following error: `TypeError: change_screen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. How can I pass `self` as an argument in `t1 = threading.Thread(target=change_screen)`??

Comment: You don't want to put your code that changes screens in another thread, that needs to run on the main thread. You should put the other function in another thread. It would be much easier and quicker to figure this out if you would post a [mcve].

Comment: I added the `start_process()` function to the question. So what I want to do is go back to the main screen after all the threads executed from the if statement are done. I tried to add a function `change_screen()` in `MainScreen` but I because it is inside a class I have to pass an argument when declaring the thread. How could I fix this??

Comment: This is getting much too complicated to discuss without a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson ok, I made the necessary changes. So what I do is change the screen in the main thread and then in another, I execute the function. So when the thread is done I want to switch back to the main screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to change back to the main screen after running a function. Modify the target function as:

```
def function1():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done")
    Clock.schedule_once(App.get_running_app().show_main_screen)


def function2():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done 2")
    Clock.schedule_once(App.get_running_app().show_main_screen)
```

The `Clock.schedule_once()` schedules something to be run on the main thread (required for changes to the UI).

And modify the `MainApp` as:

```
class MainApp(App):

    choice = ""
    source = StringProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        self.m = Manager(transition=NoTransition())  # save a reference to `Manager`
        return self.m

    def show_main_screen(self, dt):
        self.m.current = "Main Screen"  # use the saved reference to change the current screen
```

Also, in your 'kv' file, the lines:

```
manager: screen_manager
```

are not needed. That property is automatically added to each `Screen`.

Comment: Hey John! It works! I would like to do this from a function from another class. how could I do this too?? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you need to post a new question for that.

Comment: Ok then, thank you for your solutions!! I appreciate them a lot sir.